# Regular expression to check allowed characters not working in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following method to check allowed characters:

```
private boolean checkIfAllCharsAreValid(String test) {
    boolean valid = false;
    if (test.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:-_'\\s]+$")) {
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

but if test has the character `-` in it the match return false. Do i have to escape the `-`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside `[`...`]` the `-` symbol is treated specially. (You use it yourself in this special purpose in the beginning of your expression where you have `a-z`.)

You need to escape the `-` character

```
[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:\-_'\s]
              ^
```

or put it last (or first) in the `[...]` expression like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:_'\s-]
                   ^
```

---

Some further notes:

- Technically speaking all characters are valid in the empty string, so I would change from `+` to `*` in your expression.
- `String.matches` checks the full string, so the `^` and `$` are redundant.
- Your entire method could be wirtten as

  ```
  return test.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:_'\\s-]*");
  ```

Comment: Since we have `a-zA-Z0-9_` as part of the character class, wouldn't it simplify things to use `\w` instead?, i.e. `"[\\w,.;:'\\s-]*"`

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `-` at the start of the character group so that it is not interpreted as a character range.

Answer (score 2):

A `-` in a character class surrounded on both sides is a regex meta character to denote range.

To list a literal `-` in a char class you escape the `-` in the char class:

```
if (test.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:\\-_'\\s]+$")) 
                                 ^^^
```

or place the `-` at the end of char class:

```
if (test.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9,.;:_'\\s-]+$")) 
                                      ^
```

or place the `-` at the beginning of char class:

```
if (test.matches("^[-a-zA-Z0-9,.;:_'\\s]+$")) 
                    ^
```