# How do I remove this character from my regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have graciously used the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931617/check-a-textbox-for-invalid-characters-using-js-and-regular-expressions) - the Regex does appear to properly check for illegal characters when implemented like so:

```
public static boolean checkInvalidCharacter (String alphaNum) 
  {
    if (alphaNum == null) return false;

    try {
        boolean isRegex = false;
        RE r = new RE("^.*?(?=[\\^#%&$\\*:<>\\?/\\{\\|\\}]).*$");
        isRegex = r.match(alphaNum);
        System.out.println("isRegex: "+isRegex);
        System.out.println("Space");
      return r.match(alphaNum);   
    } catch (RESyntaxException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

However, we need to accept a subset of these characters (:?/*&$), and when I tried removing ":" to see if it would work, I got the error "Syntax Error:Missing operand to closure".

I assumed that the enclosed set of characters in the [] brackets would be the set of characters being checked - is this a false assumption?  And more to the point, how can I remove the valid list of characters from this RegEx so that I can compare it to my string?

Comment: Have you tried `RE r = new RE("^.*[\\^#%<>\\{\\|\\}].*$");`? I think that you can even omit all escapes with `"^.*[#%<>^{|}].*$"` as inside the  character class, the `{`, `}`, `|` and `^` not in the leading position after `[` (and `*`, `?`, `$`) lose their special meanings.

Comment: I concur with Wiktor : only the `[]` need to be escaped once (`\\[\\]`) and the `\ ` twice : `\\\\`. You can refer to [this example](https://ideone.com/N3AMdz).

Comment: I'm opting to use this whitelist instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063843/regular-expression-to-check-allowed-characters-not-working-in-java however, the suggestions to trim down and properly escape have been helpful for this question as a whole, so I will still accept an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That whole method is overly complex.

Have you tried:

```
public static boolean checkInvalidCharacter (String alphaNum) {
    return alphaNum != null && alphaNum.matches(".*[\\^#%<>\\{\\|\\}].*");
}
```

or an even better:

```
public static final String INVALID_CHARACTERS = "^#%<>{}|";
private static final Pattern INVALID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("["+Pattern.escape(INVALID_CHARACTERS)+"]");

public static boolean containsInvalidCharacters(String input) {
    return input != null && INVALID_PATTERN.matcher(input).find();
}
```

Comment: admittedly the assignment process was just to capture the error in the first place - but this and the above comments have helped considerably. I've opted for another means of solving this problem, but I think this solution is best for what I was originally trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cause of the error might be due to the fact that the regex past the `:` is incorrect; or rather the string starting from the `:` is incorrect. In fact, since the `:` is not escaped, it's not actually checking for an invalid `:` character at all; an unescaped `:` has special significance in regular expressions. I'm no expert at regex but according to the table from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm), an unescaped colon "Groups regular expressions without remembering matched text." I'm not exactly sure what that means.

I tried using this string `"^.*?(?=[\\^#%<>\\{\\|\\}]).*$"` and tested it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). This should do what you're looking for.